# Equivalence of definitions of distributions

Tags: analysis

Given a distribution $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, suppose $f\circ R_{\theta} = f$ for all $\theta$, where $R_{\theta}$ denotes the rotation through angle $\theta$.

My question is: how do we show that this is equivalent to $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} f = 0$?

What I have tried: By definition, we need to show $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} f(\phi) = -f(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\phi)=0$ for all $\phi$.

On the other hand, by definition, $f(\phi) = f\circ R_{-\theta}(\phi) = f(\phi\circ R_{\theta})$ for all $\phi$, so $f(\phi\circ R_{\theta}-\phi)=0$ and $f(\frac{\phi\circ R_{\theta}-\phi}{\theta})=0$.

So as long as we can show that $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\phi\circ R_{\theta}-\phi}{\theta} = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\phi$ *in the sense of convergence in $\mathscr{D}$.* But I don't see an easy way to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: One possibility is to consider $\Phi(\theta,x)=\phi(R_\theta x)$ as a function of three variables... and use the fact that $C^k$ on a compact implies _uniform_ continuity, uniform continuity of derivatives, etc.?

Comment: Can you show it when $f$ is a smooth function?

Comment: @paulgarrett Would this work? All we need to show is $\frac{\Phi(x,y,\tau)-\Phi(x,y,0)}{\tau}$ converge uniformly to $\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial \theta}(x,y,0)$, and same for all derivatives in $x,y$. But taking any derivative in $x,y$, say $D^{\alpha}$, we just have $\frac{D^{\alpha}\Phi(x,y,\tau)-D^{\alpha}\Phi(x,y,0)}{\tau}$ on the one side and $D^{\alpha}\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial \theta}(x,y,0) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}D^{\alpha}\Phi (x,y,0)$ on the other, and then the unif. conv. is clear say from unif. continuity of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}D^{\alpha}\Phi$ and MVT.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a smooth function then we have
$$
(f \circ R_\theta)(x,y) 
= f(x \cos\theta - y \sin\theta, x \sin\theta + y \cos\theta)
$$
so
$$
\left. \frac{d}{d\theta} (f \circ R_\theta) \right|_{\theta=0}
= -y \, \partial_x f + x \, \partial_y f
= r \partial_\theta f
.
$$

Now let $f$ be a distribution and $\phi$ a test function. Then,
$$
\left. \frac{d}{d\theta} \left< f \circ R_\theta, \phi \right> \right|_{\theta=0}
= \left. \frac{d}{d\theta} \left< f, \phi \circ R_{-\theta} \right> \right|_{\theta=0}
= \left< f, \left. \frac{d}{d\theta} (\phi \circ R_{-\theta})\right|_{\theta=0} \right> 
= \left< f,  -r \partial_\theta \phi \right>
= \left< r \partial_\theta f,  \phi \right>
.
$$

But since $f \circ R_\theta = f$ for all $\theta$ the first expression vanishes:
$$
\left. \frac{d}{d\theta} \left< f \circ R_\theta, \phi \right> \right|_{\theta=0}
= \left. \frac{d}{d\theta} \left< f, \phi \right> \right|_{\theta=0}
= 0.
$$

Thus, $\left< r \partial_\theta f,  \phi \right> = 0$ for all $\phi$ and we have $r \partial_\theta f=0,$ i.e. $\partial_\theta f=0.$

---

#### Justification of moving differentiation into the pairing

Why is the following true?
$$\left. \frac{d}{d\theta} \left< f, \phi \circ R_{-\theta} \right> \right|_{\theta=0} = \left< f, \left. \frac{d}{d\theta} (\phi \circ R_{-\theta})\right|_{\theta=0} \right>$$

To justify this we need to show that
$
\frac{1}{h}\left( \phi \circ R_{-(\theta+h)} - \phi \circ R_{-\theta} \right) \to \frac{d}{d\theta} (\phi \circ R_{-\theta})
$
in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^2).$

For a simpler notation, set $\Phi(\theta,x) = \phi(R_{-\theta}x)$ and let $\Phi'$ denote the derivative w.r.t. the first variable ($\theta$).

It should be clear that $\frac{1}{h}\left( \Phi(\theta+h, x) - \Phi(\theta, x) \right) - \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \Phi(\theta, x)$ has support in some compact set for all $\theta.$

Then note that, for $h>0,$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{h}\left( \Phi(\theta+h, x) - \Phi(\theta, x) \right) - \Phi'(\theta, x)
= 
\frac{1}{h} \int_{\theta}^{\theta+h} \Phi'(\theta', x) \, d\theta' - \Phi'(\theta, x)
\\
= 
\frac{1}{h} \int_{\theta}^{\theta+h} \left( \Phi'(\theta', x) - \Phi'(\theta, x) \right) \, d\theta'
= 
\frac{1}{h} \int_{\theta}^{\theta+h} \int_{\theta}^{\theta'} \Phi''(\theta'', x) \, d\theta'' \, d\theta'
$$
so that
$$
\left| \frac{1}{h}\left( \Phi(\theta+h, x) - \Phi(\theta, x) \right) - \Phi'(\theta, x) \right|
\leq
\frac{1}{h} \int_{\theta}^{\theta+h} \int_{\theta}^{\theta'} |\Phi''(\theta'', x)| \, d\theta'' \, d\theta'
\\
\leq \frac{1}{h} \cdot h \cdot h \cdot \sup_{\theta''} |\Phi''(\theta'', x)|
= h \|\Phi''\|.
$$
For $h<0$ we get a corresponding inequality. From this we can conclude that
$$
\frac{1}{h}\left( \Phi(\theta+h, x) - \Phi(\theta, x) \right) - \Phi'(\theta, x) \to 0
$$
uniformly as $h\to 0.$

The same is valid for all derivatives w.r.t. $x$ of $\Phi$ so $\frac{1}{h}\left( \Phi(\theta+h, x) - \Phi(\theta, x) \right) - \Phi'(\theta, x) \to 0$ in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^2).$

Comment: Yes, my question is how to justify moving the $d/d\theta$ into the distribution and onto the test function.

Comment: This step?
$$\left. \frac{d}{d\theta} \left< f, \phi \circ R_{-\theta} \right> \right|_{\theta=0}
= \left< f, \left. \frac{d}{d\theta} (\phi \circ R_{-\theta})\right|_{\theta=0} \right>$$

Comment: Yes, this step exactly.

Comment: @heron1000. I have now added a justification of that step.